# Working for US-based company remotely in Canada

Tags: working-visas, canada

I am a citizen of the Philippines. I am currently employed by a US company  and working remotely for them as a contractor. Is it possible to immigrate to Canada and maintain the same setup?

- I will be at home, working for a US company as a contractor. No job is taken away from any eligible Canadian.
- I will be filing income taxes in Canada.

If yes, what would be the visa appropriate for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are:

- Doing all work for a US company that has no Canadian ties (no locations, no customers, etc)
- Being paid in US funds through a US bank account
- Doing the work remotely, i.e. via telephone or internet
- Will continue to be eligible to work for the US company (this is the big thing, based on your post; if you are no longer in the US, will the company still be allowed to employ you?)

You should be able to work in Canada under any type of visa that you are otherwise authorized for and should not need a work permit.

See CIC's [definition of work](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/work/about.asp) for immigration purposes, which exempts working remotely through a foreign company where remuneration is also made in that company's country.